# How do I give a name to the SSL certificate purchased in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have seen some pages like this: https://www.crecerseguros.pe/ In which they give a name to the certificate. I would like to know its can be done in the SSL certificate purchased in the Azure Marketplace.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly7Kr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to [Extended Validity Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) (commonly known as EV SSL). Many of the Certificate Authorities issue them at a higher cost than the regular SSL Certificates.

EV SSL Certificates don't add much value, as it used be earlier. See [Troy Hunt's excellent writeup](https://www.troyhunt.com/extended-validation-certificates-are-dead/) on this.

Comment: *Validation* is what CA does to check applicant's identity; *Validity* is the period of time reliers should accept the cert (i.e. from 'notbefore' until 'notafter').

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the **Organization name** in Browser is only possible by installing the EV SSL Certificate on your server.

But to issue an **EV SSL Certificate**, you need to pass through a tough organization validation process where the Certificate Authorities will asked to submit the legal business documents to assure you are a genuine and trusted organization.

Check how Website with [EV SSL Certificate looks like in different browsers.](https://aboutssl.org/what-is-extended-validation-green-address-bar-ssl/)